# Map a Static Page to Custom Post Type archive page

Tags: wordpress, mapping, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've registered a custom post type named `portfolio`. It's archive enabled, so I can visit it's archive page by visiting `http://example.com/portfolio/` permalink.

Now, I want to create a static page with any given slug e.g. `courses` and I want to resolve this static page ID (as slug may change) to `archive-portfolio.php` page mentioned above.

Additionally, I also want to use that static page to be able to set as front page (just like any other static page) without losing it's ability to map to portfolio archive page.

How do I achieve this functionality?

**Note:** I want to implement this functionality in a commercial theme, so, any solution suggested must work out of the box i.e. without forcing end-user to deal with the file strucutre.

Comment: Wouldn't creating `page-courses.php` and requiring `archive-portfolio.php` inside it work?

Comment: it might work, but each time page slug is changed it'll require the end user to change the file name too (I'm developing a theme for mass audience). So, I need a robust solution; where the end user only have to assign a static page to custom post type, only once(i.e. may be from a drop down menu in theme customizer)

Comment: it can be id instead of a slug.

Comment: Still, it would be better to provide end-user this functionality without forcing them to deal with core files.

Comment: they won't have to deal with core files in any way. you can also do it without making them deal with theme files as well.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion here. The static page would be created on/after custom post type plugin activation, automatically or manually. In any case the page ID would be generated on fly. So, not knowing the page ID beforehand, the end user must have to change `page-{ID}.php` file name and I want to keep end-user away from dealing with file structure.

Comment: What stops you from creating the file after you create page? You can ID back from the function call to create page.

Comment: So, you are suggesting creating a file automatically upon/after CPT plugin activation and its ID would be returned from a function. I'm not sure how to do it. However, won't it cause possible file permission issue on different hosting providers?

Comment: Not really suggesting, it's not really that great of an option to have out in the wild for mass usage on different services. This would work if you were doing it for itself (you should have specified in your question that you're looking for solution which would work out of the box for everyone or at least majority)

Comment: Although I've explained it in my first comment, Now, I've also added it as a note in original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105476/discussion-between-muhammad-faisal-and-igor-yavych).